# Copy words from lines and append to lines in another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have file test1 with lines like this:

```
A B C
D E F
...
```

and I want to have file test2 with lines:

```
DDD EEE FFF A
DDD EEE FFF D
...
```

where A and D are copied from first column of test1 file after phrase DDD EEE FFF to test2 file

I started like below,

```
cat test1 | echo "DDD EEE FFF " `awk '{print $1}'` > test2
```

but of course it only adds phrase DDD EEE FFF once and then appends A, D to it which is not what I want

```
DDD EEE FFF  A D
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First remove everything from the first whitespace on, then add your phrase to the beginning:

```
sed 's/ .*//;s/^/DDD EEE FFF /' test1
```

Comment: grateful for both , unfortunately can only reward one..

Comment: @irom Then reward Philippos, he was first to answer.

Answer (score 6):

[Philippos' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/391604/203203) is good. If you are more comfortable with `awk`, try this:

```
awk '{print "DDD EEE FFF " $1}' test1 > test2
```